# Regex making the browser unresponsive

Tags: javascript, regex, timeout

I have the following regex which works fine at parsing a gradient

```
/(?:\s*)(?:linear|radial)-gradient\s*\(((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(]*)*)\)/g
```

When an invalid string is passed to the `regex.exec` function like so:

```
var regex = /(?:\s*)(?:linear|radial)-gradient\s*\(((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(]*)*)\)/g;
var test = "radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, white";
regex.exec(test);
```

The browser hangs with an unresponsive script until it times out.

When I tried this [as a regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kJxxqb/1), I get a timeout with the message

> Your expression took too long to finish and was terminated. Please
>   increase the timeout and try again.

Can you help me rewrite the regex so it won't timeout if it cannot find a match? I, of course, would also like to know why it times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to keep a double nested star quantifier:

```
/(?:\s*)(?:linear|radial)-gradient\s*\(((?:\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(])*)\)/g
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJxxqb/3)

Comment: Thank you! I would not have caught that. It took awhile to figure out why the regex still worked without the nested star. I still don't understand why the regex timeout though.